# How to remove unnecessary log: "Host keys are loaded." from Application Insights

Tags: logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Function 1.x and Application Insights integration.
Every Http trigger is called, there is a log: "Host keys are loaded" that is recorded in Application Insights.
See the picture below:

[image]

The category is: "Host.Keys", I also checked link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring and does not find any information about this category.

I also modified the host.json follow:

```
"defaultLevel": "Warning",
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
        "Function": "Information",
        "Host.Keys": "None"
  }
```

However it does not work.
Could you show me how to stop recording unneccessary log?

Comment: Do you want only the error informations and your logs ?

Comment: I means limit the system information log. "Host keys are loaded" log does not give any useful information.

Comment: Try changing it to `Trace` and see if it helps. I have'nt tested this

Comment: Trace is low level than Information and None, it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

@duy Please use the below host.json:

```
{
  "logger": {
    "categoryFilter": {
      "defaultLevel": "Warning",
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
        "Function": "Information",
        "Host.Keys": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only Error level and above logs for Host.Keys will be sent to Application Insights.

Comment: Thank you. Acctually I also tried this way, but it does not work now. I reported this issue to MS and watting for his report.

Answer (score 0):

I created an MS tickets and they find out the issue. There is an bug that happen only in Japan East regions (change Host.Keys=None work in other regions). MS will release a package to fix soon.